# cannot be cast to android.app.activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I run my application I get these errors, I'mm trying to make an app with RSS

Photo2.java

```
package com.otticafotobenzi.ofbshop;

import com.otticafotobenzi.R;

public class Photo2 extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;
private Context mContext;
Button buttonCan;
Button buttonFuj;
Button buttonNik;
Button buttonOly;
Button buttonPana;
Button buttonPen;
Button buttonSon;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(
        new SwipeGestureDetector());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo2);
    buttonCan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCan);
    buttonFuj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFuj);
    buttonNik = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNik);
    buttonOly = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOly);
    buttonPana = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPana);
    buttonPen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPen);
    buttonSon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSon);
    buttonCan.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFuj.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonNik.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonOly.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonPana.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonPen.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSon.setOnClickListener(this);
    mContext = this;
    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
    mViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonCan:
        Intent loader_rssnik = new Intent(this, RssService.class); //problem here
        startActivity(loader_rssnik);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonFuj:
        Intent loader_rsscan = new Intent(this, RssService.class);
        startActivity(loader_rsscan);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonNik:
        Intent loader_rssfuji = new Intent(this, RssServiceNik.class);
        startActivity(loader_rssfuji);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonOly:
        Intent loader_rssoly = new Intent(this, RssService.class);
        startActivity(loader_rssoly);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonPana:
        Intent loader_rsspen = new Intent(this, RssService.class);
        startActivity(loader_rsspen);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonPen:
        Intent loader_rsspan = new Intent(this, RssService.class);
        startActivity(loader_rsspan);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonSon:
        Intent loader_rssson = new Intent(this, RssService.class);
        startActivity(loader_rssson);
        break;

    }

}
class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        mContext, R.anim.left_in));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        mContext, R.anim.left_out));
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
                return true;
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        mContext, R.anim.right_in));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        mContext, R.anim.right_out));
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.photography, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.otticafotobenzi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ofbshop.Loader" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ofbshop.Home" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ofbshop.Photography" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photography">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ofbshop.Photo2" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photography">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ofbshop.Optics" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_optics">
    </activity>       
    <activity android:name=".rss.Constants" />
    <activity android:name=".rss.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".rss.RssAdapter" />
    <activity android:name=".rss.RssFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".rss.RssItem" />
    <activity android:name=".rss.RssParser" />
    <activity android:name=".rss.RssService" />
    <activity android:name=".rss.RssServiceNik" />

</application>
```

RssService.java

```
package com.otticafotobenzi.rss;

public class RssService extends IntentService {

private static final String RSS_LINK = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/PhotoRumors?format=xml";
public static final String ITEMS = "items";
public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";

public RssService() {
    super("RssService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
    List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
    try {
        RssParser parser = new RssParser();
        rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) rssItems);
    ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
    receiver.send(0, bundle);
}

public InputStream getInputStream(String link) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Exception while retrieving the input stream",
                e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

and this is the error in logcat with genymotion emulator android 4.4

```
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044): Process: com.otticafotobenzi, PID: 2044
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.otticafotobenzi/com.otticafotobenzi.rss.RssService}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.otticafotobenzi.rss.RssService cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.otticafotobenzi.rss.RssService cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
02-12 17:04:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `startService()` ...

Comment: Now i try...but this is the result...sob02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RssService]
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): Process: com.otticafotobenzi, PID: 2173
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):  at com.otticafotobenzi.rss.RssService.onHandleIntent(RssService.java:42)
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)

Comment: 02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<activity android:name=".rss.RssService" />
```

to

```
<service android:name=".rss.RssService" />
```

And if you want to start service use method

```
startService(Intent);
```

by

```
startActivity(Intent);
```

Comment: 02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RssService]
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): Process: com.otticafotobenzi, PID: 2173
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): at com.otticafotobenzi.rss.RssService.onHandleIntent(RssService.java:42)
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-12 17:53:58.735: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: I'm trying to find reason but I don't know. I am afraid that I don't have enough information. Post your problem in new thread. Describe it. Add full info from stack trace

Comment: I am glad that I could help you with previous issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a different method for services:

```
Intent loader_rssnik = new Intent(this, RssService.class);
startService(loader_rssfuji);
```

Comment: I think that the basic problem is with service registration on AndroidManifest. He makes mistake in manifest